# Dart - Make a function with mandatory type

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function in dart

```
someFunction<T extends SomeClass>() {
  // some code here
}
```

I want to be mandatory to specify type T

Answer (score 0):

The language specification says (https://dart.dev/guides/language/spec#h.dkzw3xyky3rs) :

> A type parameter T may be suffixed with an extends clause that
> specifies the upper bound for T. If no extends clause is present, the
> upper bound is Object. It is a static type warning if a type parameter
> is a supertype of its upper bound. The bounds of type variables are a
> form of type annotation and have no effect on execution in production
> mode.

So maybe something like the following could work:

```
<T> somefunction<T extends SomeType>(){}
```

I have not tested it by myself but let me know if it works.

Comment: Actually my function's type T extends from another class, but when I put the <T> at the beginning shows me this error: `Expected a method, getter, setter or operator declaration.
This appears to be incomplete code. Try removing it or completing it.dart(expected_executable)`

Comment: Oh you can just remove it, it was a leftover for a method return type

Answer (score -1):

I think your initial `<T>` is throwing it off.  That should just be `T`.

Comment: This answer does not make any sense to me.  Are you saying that `someFunction<T>()` should be `someFunctionT()`?  Huh?

Comment: Someone had something like `<T> somefunction ...` and that should have been `T somefunction ...`.  Wasn't you, so I was answering the wrong poster. :)